# How to setTextColor based on String value in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to set text color of textview based on string **STATUS**.

If **Status** = **RED**, text should be red; if **Status** = **GREEN**, text should be green. I've tried many solutions but I cant still set color...

Here is my code:

**Adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewItem viewItem = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewItem = new ViewItem();
        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, null);
        viewItem.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        viewItem.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        viewItem.tvPoints = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_points);
        viewItem.tvStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        TextView tvpkt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_points);
        TextView tvstatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

        String status = tvstatus.getText().toString();

        if (status.equals("Red")) {
            tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (status.equals("Green")) {
            tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    } else {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewItem.tvDescription.setText(valueList.get(position).Description);
    viewItem.tvDate.setText(valueList.get(position).Date);
    viewItem.tvPoints.setText(valueList.get(position).Points);
    viewItem.tvStatus.setText(valueList.get(position).Status);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on your conditions for checking the `status` variable, what value(s) do you see?

Comment: You are reading your text and setting the color on different textviews. Is that the intended behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `String status` doesn't match the conditions in the `if-statement` later.

One way to skip the case sensitivity of the String is to use [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) which basically compares two Strings, ignoring case considerations.

Something like this:

```
if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Red")){
   tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Green")){
   tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Another way is to capitalize the `status` before comparison by using [toUpperCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) method, something like this:

```
String status = tvstatus.getText().toString().toUpperCase;
```

Then compare it with an uppercased version of strings:

```
if(status.equals("RED")){
   tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else if(status.equals("GREEN")){
   tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay just the sequence is wrong. Also only view inflation and viewholder creation should be done in case convertview is null. Modify your code like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ViewItem viewItem = null;

if(convertView == null)
{
    viewItem = new ViewItem();

    LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, null);



    viewItem.tvDescription= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    viewItem.tvDate= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    viewItem.tvPoints= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_points);
    viewItem.tvStatus= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

    convertView.setTag(viewItem);
}

else
{
    viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
}


viewItem.tvDescription.setText(valueList.get(position).Description);
viewItem.tvDate.setText(valueList.get(position).Date);
viewItem.tvPoints.setText(valueList.get(position).Points);
viewItem.tvStatus.setText(valueList.get(position).Status);


TextView tvpkt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_points);

String status= viewItem.tvstatus.getText().toString();

if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Red"))
{
    tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Green"))
{
    tvpkt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}


return convertView;
}
```